# Why do I get a ValidationException

Tags: mysql, xml, orbeon

I try to extract the XML data for a form using the REST service like this :

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/service/mysql/crud/<App-name>/<form-name>/data/<document_id>/data.xml
```

I first had to adapt the properties-local.xml to allow public access to the service, and now I can get in, but the server returns an HTTP 500, and I see a nice org.orbeon.oxf.common.ValidationException being throwed up.

In the stack trace I see that it tries to perform some XSLT transformation, but I only ask for the xml form data, so it should'nt. Or am I wrong ?

The MySQL Persistence Layer is working well.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly call the specific persistence layers, because they need to receive special configuration headers. Instead, call the persistence service:

```
http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/service/persistence/crud/<App-name>/<form-name>/data/<document_id>/data.xml
```

The persistence service passes what is needed to the persistence layers.